# Youtube videos don't play in Android Webview (Target 23)

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube, android-6.0-marshmallow

I accidently changed the target sdk version of my application to 23 from 17 and uploaded it on Google playstore.

After that, I found out that youtube videos on the webview in my app doesn't start playing video but just keep loading forever.

I found out that it's because Google stopped supporting plugins on webview in target sdk 23.

The Youtube video player also looks different from the one that used to show when the target sdk was 17.

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

    WebSettings set = mWebView.getSettings();

    set.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
    set.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);       
    set.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);      
    set.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);    
    set.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    set.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    getWindow().addFlags(16777216);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This is the source I used for my webview, and it was working all right.

Since it's impossible to lower down the target sdk version since it was uploaded on google playstore, please let me know if there is any way to make youtube video players on webpages work in android webview in target sdk 23.

---

Thanks for your kind answers.
But in this case, I have to display random web pages with youtube videos in iframe, which are not in my control.

So I wonder if there's any way to make the videos play in webview just by changing some options or by overriding some class etc..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use webview, use videoview and set url like

```
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);         MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);         mc.setAnchorView(v);         mc.setMediaPlayer(v);         v.setMediaController(mc);         v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(linkN));         v.start();
```